# ArrayAdapter with unknown list types

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

Is there any way I can do something like int the code below? I have many different spinners and lists and I wonder if there is an approach where I don't have to do many checks:

```
    private void setSpinner(Spinner spinner, List<?> l){
    if (l != null || !l.isEmpty()){
    ArrayAdapter<?> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<?>(
            Prototype_activity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            l);
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could lose the type for `ArrayAdapter` and just pass the list of objects. It will work as `ArrayAdapter` simply calls `toString` on the objects passed to it, method available to any java object.

```
private void setSpinner(Spinner spinner, List<?> l){
    if (l != null || !l.isEmpty()){
    ArrayAdapter myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(
            Prototype_activity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
            l);
    spinner.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }
}
```